# How to use APM jvm.memory.heap.used in ELK stack

Tags: elasticsearch, heap-memory, apm, elk

Is there an example available about how to use jvm.memory.heap.used
To get this data in kibana.

Answer (score 0):

There are few steps to follow before you will be able to create simple visualization for `jvm.memory.heap.used` metric.

**Download and start APM server, you will find instructions [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/server/current/installing.html)**

For osx you can do this with following commands:

```
curl -L -O https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/apm-server/apm-server-7.2.0-darwin-x86_64.tar.gz
tar xzvf apm-server-7.2.0-darwin-x86_64.tar.gz
cd apm-server-7.2.0-darwin-x86_64/

./apm-server -e
```

**Run your app with an attached agent**

```
java -javaagent:/path_to_agent/elastic-apm-agent-1.9.0.jar \
     -Delastic.apm.service_name=my-application \
     -Delastic.apm.server_url=http://localhost:8200 \
     -Delastic.apm.secret_token= \
     -Delastic.apm.application_packages=org.example \
     -jar Main.jar
```

**Make sure elasticsearch is receiving data from apm agent**

[image]

**Prepare index patter for apm indices**

[image]

**Create a visualization**

[image]

[image]

I want to show `jvm.memory.heap.used` usage over time so I'll select date histogram for a bucket

[image]

and max value in a given time by configuring metrics like this

[image]

in the end, we should see something like this

[image]

You can find an interactive tutorial [inside](http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/home/tutorial/apm?_g=()) Kibana about gathering APM data from java applications. If you fill find creating visualizations problematic, check [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tutorial-visualizing.html) tutorial.

Hope that helps.